# most common version of rails used on hosting websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting, web-hosting

This is kind of a general question, but I think as someone who is trying to host a rails site it deserves attention: what is the most common version of rails that is compatible with hosting websites like godaddy, dreamhost, etc, and what is the best hosting company to do this on?

I'm very surprised at how difficult it is to host a rails site; for example, godaddy flat-out doesn't support rails at all and dreamhost only has ruby 1.8.7 on their shared server, with which rails doesn't even function; you need ruby 1.9.2 or higher according to the official rails website.  You have to install the newest version of ruby and rails on your personal host space, which is several hundred MB and because of this costs $35/month now (more than double the minimum $15/mo 300 mb.  Seems excessive; why don't they just have it on their shared server?  It takes 5 minutes to install.

I built a rails site locally and thought I should install ruby 2.1.2 and rails 4.1.4 because they are the newest, but even after installing the new rails on my dreamhost space the website doesn't function because rails is not set up correctly (works fine locally however).  The customer support people, while they have an awesome staff and a very comprehensive help wiki in general, haven't been able to help me.

After going 0/2 on hosting sites for a VERY simple website, I guess I should have done my homework better, but do people generally use an older version of rails or ruby that is easier to use?  Which is the most common, and why?  Also, what is the best website to host a rails app on?

Comment: Try to search for specifically Ruby hosting (like Heroku, Ninefold, EngineYard...) rather than generic hosting like Dreamhost (that runs Ruby 1.8.7, which has been [retired](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/) for a year now).

Comment: Heroku always does great job for me and keeps updated with newest version of Ruby and Rails. Heroku is free (for basic) as well with many free addons there. You can point the heroku to your own domain with some little configuration. Most of common hosting services doesn't keep up with the newest version, they're still stuck at Ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.3 and Rails 3 :(

Comment: I didn't know heroku could be pointed to your own domain, that's probably what i'll do now that I know that.  Free > $35/month for barely supported ruby/rails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 "levels" of hosting:

---

**Basic**

90's era hosts (very antiquated - only providing "low level" solutions)

This type of provider is what VistaPrint is to printing - many "small businesses" who just want a crappy website and spend $5/year on hosting will get one of these. They'll get an email, their own domain & 10mb of space.

Stay clear of this type of hosting ;)

---

**Shared**

2000 - 2010 era hosting (some extensibility but not a lot)

This is where reseller hosting & "virtual private servers" started to become the norm. Your Site5, GoDaddy, Hostgator, Dreamhosts of the world fit into this bracket.

These are predominantly designed for rigid script-based websites - forums, blogs & other server-centric software. They don't allow much flexibility, apart from CPanel or the like

You basically get a slice of a box running linux (not VPS)

---

**Cloud**

2010+ era hosting (highly flexible & extensible)

Although "cloud" hosting is literally just "VPS" hosting, the main difference is you get complete control of how the server will run. Your application can run on the box with all the dependencies you need, allowing you to create data-driven, rich experiences.

Providers such as [Heroku](http://heroku.com), [Rackspace](http://rackspace.com), [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com), [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com) & [Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com) fit into this category.

The main benefits / attributes of these providers are complete autonomy over what you run on the box - as well as SSH & connectivity support. These basically allow you to create dependency-driven applications

---

**Companies**

If you've ever set up a web server manually, you'll understand how difficult it will be to manage the entire infrastructure of a hosting *company*

I would suggest that the companies, as I've described above, will likely remain as long as people pay them (and they will). This means if you want true dependency-driven support, you'll want to stick with the cloud providers; as these will allow you the most flexibility & extensibility

We use Rackspace currently - highly recommended!!!!!!!

There are tons of other choices though :)

Comment: Thanks, this was enlightening.  I think heroku will be the one for me, my website is fairly simple and I don't foresee an explosive growth....just want to host some rails-based pages!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the most popular service for hosting a simple Rails app is [Heroku](http://heroku.com). It's easy enough that a relative beginner can get up and running quickly, but provides room to grow (for example, [Rap Genius](http://rapgenius.com), a very highly trafficked Rails app, [was hosted on Heroku](http://success.heroku.com/rapgenius)). It also supports Rails 4. They have [well-written guides](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4) on deploying a Rails application.

Other popular hosts are [Digital Ocean](http://digitalocean.com) and [Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Ruby), though it's a bit trickier to get set up on these unless you are experienced with deploying Rails applications.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to not let the host dictate what version of ruby/rails to use. If you're starting a new project it's best to use the latest version of ruby/rails so you don't start out behind the curve. Find a host that works with what you are using! As @npostolovski mentioned, Heroku is a great way to go for beginners (and experts too if you don't have any pressing conflicts) and generally supports the latest version of ruby/rails.